Do we need "including" between "the entertainment business" and "...both what we've seen..."?
From Disney sees modest revenue growth, strong theme park demand

I would just call this as a bit of a slowdown that's being more than
offset by the entertainment business [including] both what we've seen so far and
our expectations for Moana 2 as well as Mufasa.

Should we insert 'including' here? Does "both what we've seen so far and our expectations for Moana 2 as well as Mufasa." function as appositive?

No. This is a written transcript of a conference call, so I would read it as a pause. (The transcript could perhaps benefit from a comma.) Including would imply that there are more categories than what we've seen and our expectations. But in reality those two categories cover all of past/present/future. No need to add including.

Should we insert words when other people talk, if they're not our young children? No, we shouldn't.

There's another error in the sentence.  It should be "call this" or "describe this as", not "call this as".  You shouldn't use examples like this for studying grammar. It seems to be a transcript of a telephone call. There also appears to be a missing comma before "both". This could be a simple typo. The other error might just be a mistake.

Short answer - no. It's grammatically wrong without your insertion, and it is wrong with it, too.
This appears to be a transcript of extemporaneous speech, and so it should not be scrutinised heavily against the rules of grammar. The mistake you have spotted is certainly not the only one - "I would just call this as a bit of a slowdown", for example, is wrong. You don't call something 'as'. You call something [x], or describe it as [x].
If you wanted to insert a word in the space to make more sense I would imagine the word 'considering' would be the most appropriate and in line with what it is trying to say. But even with that correction, the whole quotation doesn't stand up to close grammatical scrutiny.
